# Make firebase server rule change properties

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server, google-cloud-functions, rules

Lets say i have this structure

```
-Users
     - ID
        - NumberOfWeapons
        - Strength
        - CombinedPower
```

Is it possible to for server rules to update CombinedPower based on changes to NumberOfWeapons and Strength, or do i have to use firebase functions to listen for changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in language that makes the database server do such aggregations for you. You'd either do that directly from the client (validating with server-side security rules), or through Cloud Functions (which is really similar to a client, but then runs in an environment you can trust).